# Keypress trigger TextEdit update Android

Tags: java, android, python, android-widget, tkinter

I have an app I'm trying to translate which uses tkinter and python, but I'm not comfortable with Java. I already have the UI but it's the coding part in Java I'm having trouble with.
The thing I want is a
"input triggered by change > processing > insert processed data into other EditText"
I know about the addTextChangedListener and TextWatcher, but the problem is that I can't code Java and won't inserting create a infinite loop, for example if I get input from 1 then it get's processed and inserted in another, then won't it start the same process thus creating a infinite loop?

Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your concern is an infinite loop, then use onKeyPressed() instead of onTextChanged():

```
text.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener()
{
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        // Put your code here
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: That I didn't come to think of that, Thanks!